# Jboss 7 - Auto Switch back from Secondary Database to Primary Database

Tags: java, mysql, database, jboss

I currently have a configuration in my Data-source tags of Standalone.xml of jboss 7 to connect to a Secondary Database on Fail over from Primary Database.This is happening Fine.

Can i make my jboss 7 to check for primary DB connection every now and then so that if the Failed Primary Database has come up now, inform jboss to connect back to primary Database?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409111/database-fail-over-in-jboss-data-sources . Try the question's accepted answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/10586855/4807777)

Comment: Hi  Laurentiu, thank you but will that work same for Jboss 7?

Comment: Maybe not the exact same syntax. You can use the ironjacamar ( http://www.ironjacamar.org/ ) to convert these configuration files into the format expected by JBoss AS 7 as described here http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-datasource/migrate-jboss-datasources-howto .

Comment: thanks for the redirection to a more informative question. but still it does not work for jboss 7 and the above links which you have shown me is not pretty helpful.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add this piece of xml in your datasource

```
<validation>
<valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleValidConnectionChecker"/>
<validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
</validation>
```

Comment: I see there is something like oracle valid connection.. But I am using mysql

Comment: according to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-jboss.html you should use   com.mysql.jdbc.integration.jboss.MysqlValidConnectionChecker
 but never tried

Comment: The link you shared explains about jboss 4.. But I am facing problems with jboss 7

Comment: it's a mysql class the class is the same for both JB4 and JB7 and even other AS try it

Comment: in the following link you can see the validation connection checker in action in JBoss 7 https://developer.jboss.org/message/722403?_sscc=t